# Flask Sqlalchemy No Errors but not updating sqlite3 virtual table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a small flask app that I am working on.  It consists of a search box, which is using a select statement outside of Sqlalchemy to do a "full text search" on a virtual fts5 table

```
sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM items INNER JOIN Restaurants on Restaurants.rest_id = items.restaurant_id WHERE items MATCH '{}' ORDER BY item_rank DESC".format(q)
    crsr = conn.execute(sqlstr)
    search_data = crsr.fetchall()
    crsr.close()
```

The user gets the results and then can THumbs up a menu item from the results,when that happens I take them to a "vote" flask route to record the thumbs up AND make a log in my analytics table.  and then redirect to last page.  This is where it gets wonky.

```
db.session.query(items).filter(items.id==item_id).update({items.item_rank:items.item_rank +1})
        db.session.commit()
        ## RECORDING IT IN ANALYTICS
        voted_item = Analytics(user_id=str(current_user),action=str('vote'),item_id=item_id)
        db.session.add(voted_item)
        db.session.commit()
```

I don't get any errors in my log files. When I hit vote I get the flask message that says It was successful.  I am successfully logging the vote in a separate Analytics table,  but for some reason its not recording it in the items table.

Ive tried a few things.  I went back to sql statement to update the items virtual table, something like this:

```
sqlstr = "UPDATE items SET item_rank = item_rank +1 where id = {}".format(item_id)
        crsr = conn.execute(sqlstr)
        crsr.close()
```

But I was getting data base is locked errors, I assume because I was access db outside of Sqlalchemy orm...Any ideas?  Because of a fts5, virtual table?  going back and forth form sql to orm?

Comment: sqllite is pretty sensitive to concurrently, so that might explain the locking issues. Is the query that's updating the analytics table and items table using different database connections? I'd lean towards using sqlalchemy, as you get all the benefits of security and features that it offers. Also, just a sidenote, if you do use raw sql, be sure to use variable parameterization instead of string concatenation (as is the case with the format command above) to prevent sql-injection exploits.

Comment: Thanks Joe, yes they are using the same connections. Thanks for the reminder on the params!  Maybe I'll start with a dict for analytics...